# SQL - need to print the same number of records and same product for customer in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with `customer_id` and `product_id`

```
customer_id product_id
c1          1
c1          2
c1          3
c2          1
c2          2
c2          3
c3          5
c4          5
c5          3
```

I need to filter the same number of customers who brought the same number of products.

In addition to that, the customer (c5,3) is not valid because he have same product_id but the number of records are not matched with the customers.

This is the query i have tried

```
SELECT T1.ORDER_ID FROM @ORDER T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @ORDER T2
                  WHERE T2.PRODUCT_ID = T1.PRODUCT_ID
                        AND T2.ORDER_ID != T1.ORDER_ID
                  GROUP BY T2.ORDER_ID)
```

The output should be like this

customer_id product_id

```
customer_id product_id
c1 1
c1 2
c1 3
c2 1
c2 2
c2 3
c3 5
c4 5
```

Comment: What is the table structure

Comment: What is your expected result? What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question and add a bit more information. Could you provide us with an expected output. Please also let us know what query you've tried already yourself.

Comment: I dont need last record (i.e., c5, 3) because the customer have same product id comparing to the customers c1 and c2. but the number of products are not matched.

Comment: On the expected output it is unclear why customer C5 isn't returned. Sorry I don't see the reason why it is needed to be filtered. It is only once in the starting table.

Comment: @MBijen -- Because the customer c5 has brought the product, but the number of products are not matched with any of the customers in the table. So c5 need not be returned.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @MBijen -- Oracle

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below approach, see if it applies in your case too. It doesn't seem like the best solution, but it works.

**TEST_DROP1:**

```
cust_id Prod_id
C1  1
C1  2
C1  3
C2  1
C2  2
C2  3
C3  5
C4  5
C5  3
```

**Solution:**

Step 1:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DROP2 AS
SELECT CUST_ID,
  LISTAGG(PRODUCT_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID) prods
FROM TEST_DROP1
GROUP BY CUST_ID;
```

TEST_DROP2:

```
cust_id prod_id
C1  1,2,3
C2  1,2,3
C3  5
C4  5
C5  3
```

Run the below query,

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST_DROP1
WHERE cust_id IN
  (SELECT CUST_ID
  FROM TEST_DROP2
  WHERE PRODS IN
    ( SELECT PRODS FROM TEST_DROP2 GROUP BY PRODS HAVING COUNT(1)>1
    )
  )
ORDER BY CUST_ID,
  product_id;**
```

Result:

```
C1  1
C1  2
C1  3
C2  1
C2  2
C2  3
C3  5
C4  5
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Please let me know if you have any alternative methods to achieve the results in a faster manner.